# From Powershell, how do you launch an executable in administrator mode under a different user context?

Tags: powershell

I am guessing that Start-Process will be used, but I am uncertain how exactly to accomplish these two things at once.

The user is a local user and is a member of Administrators.

Additionally there can be no user input required.

Update: Here is what I have tried and why it did not work.
As Keith Suggested, I tried doing the following:

```
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "opensesame" -Force
$cred = new-object system.management.automation.pscredential 'John',$passwd
Start-Process powershell.exe -credential $cred
```

This did not launch the powershell window in administrator mode. Adding the runas verb does not work because start-process has [two completely separate ways to call it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347667.aspx), one of which takes -Verb as a parameter and one of which takes -Credential:

```
Start-Process [-FilePath] <string> [[-ArgumentList] <string[]>] [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-LoadUserProfile] [-NoNewWindow] [-PassThru] [-RedirectStandardError <string>] [-RedirectStandardInput <string>] [-RedirectStandardOutput <string>] [-UseNewEnvironment] [-Wait] [-WorkingDirectory <string>] [<CommonParameters>]

Start-Process [-FilePath] <string> [[-ArgumentList] <string[]>] [-PassThru] [-Verb <string>] [-Wait] [-WindowStyle {<Normal> | <Hidden> | <Minimized> | <Maximized>}] [-WorkingDirectory <string>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

This means that the following returns an error:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -credential $cred -verb runas
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "opensesame" -Force
$cred = new-object system.management.automation.pscredential 'John',$passwd
Start-Process powershell.exe -credential $cred
```

This [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714574.aspx) has more information on scripts that use credentials.

Comment: Yeah, forgot that those two parameters were mutually exclusive.  Removed that bit from the answer.  I'll look into this a bit more.  I take it that UAC is enabled on this system?

Comment: Yes it is. This is running on an Azure Worker Role, which is why it has the strict automation and user requirements.